# How do I trigger exit/deactivate logic on a Durandal view?

Tags: javascript, viewmodel, setinterval, durandal

I have my Durandal viewmodel for which the activation is working great

```
define(function (require) {

var vm = {
    activate: activate
};
// ========= 
// snip snip 
// ========= 


function activate() {
    // Setup here

};
```

But on exit of the viewmodel I want to tear down something, by the docs there is a deactivate method but I can't get it work.

```
function deactivate(isClose) {
    // Teardown here
};
```

Do Durandal viewmodels not have the deactivate method or am doing anything obviously wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took another look at my code and I hadn't specified deactivate in my viewmodel:

So ...

```
var vm = {
    activate: activate
};
```

becomes ...

```
var vm = {
    activate: activate,
    deactivate: deactivate,
};
```